# How to hide a particular View controller on selected answer or button?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

I am developing an app where it has 10 questions to be asked. Each question is on a new view controller namely `FirstQuestionViewController`, `SecondViewController` and so on. Now some questions are based on the answers of second question. Basically answers are answered via YES or NO button. If the answer of second question is NO then Question no 8 & 10(`ViewControllers`) should be `hidden` else it should be `visible`. I am not able to do this. Plz Help.

Comment: can you use uiview instead if viewcontroller???

Comment: why did you take one view controller for one question? why not all question in one view controller?

Comment: bcs your show and hidden problem easily solved  by using view.

Comment: Use xib for each question. it will be easy to use.

Comment: using storyboard segue identifiers and if else condition may be the possible way

Answer (score 0):

Use a navigation controller.

Initiate it with the view controller for your first question, and each time the user answers the current question you push into the navigation a new view controller for the next question.

You can "push" either:

- Programmatically (code:
  `self.navigationController.pushViewController(nextViewController, animated:true)`, or
- [Using segues](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_storyboard/Chapters/StoryboardSegue.html).

In Xcode, start with the "Single View Application" template.
Next, go to the storyboard, choose your only view controller, and go to the menu bar, and choose `Editor > Embed in > Navigation Controller`.

See [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/NavigationControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011313-CH2-SW1) on navigation controllers.

---

Regarding as to how to selectively hide *some* questions from the normal flow, you should keep track of the user's answers somewhere it is accessible from all view controllers (a singleton, or the static properties of a struct, etc.) and incorporate logic that helps you decide **which question** (view controller) to push next, based on those answers.

Comment: i have used navigation controller @NicolasMiari

Answer (score 0):

you can navigate your one controller to another controller using 'PushViewContoller'.

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:nextController animated:true];
```